# JDIC Library Path

Tags: jdic, unsatisfiedlinkerror, java.library.path

I have the following line in my java app

webBrowser = new WebBrowser(new URL("http://java.net"));

It is causing the following error

```
    org.jdesktop.jdic.init.JdicInitException: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no jdic in java.library.path
at org.jdesktop.jdic.init.JdicManager.initBrowserNative(Unknown Source)
at org.jdesktop.jdic.browser.WebBrowser.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
at Leech.leecher$1.actionPerformed(leecher.java:41)
```

Any idea how to rectify it

Answer (score 0):

You may need to add **jdic.dll** to the root of your Project.

Then add **IeEmbed.exe** and **MozEmbed.exe** to the same directory where jdicXXX.jar locate.

You can download them from below location

https://www.dropbox.com/s/qt3ax417t994q4h/JDIC.zip?dl=0